# What is the difference between psql and postgresql-client?

Tags: postgresql, docker, psql

I have access to two postgres database servers on different hosts. On server A I access the client using:

```
psql -h localhost -U user -W db_name

db_name=>
```

And on the second host B I access the client using (docker image):

```
docker run -it --rm  --network fiware_default jbergknoff/postgresql-client\
   postgresql://postgres:password@postgres-db:5432/postgres

postgres=#
```

Now I need to dump database file copied from A (now on B) using:

```
psql -U postgres -d targetdb -f sourcedb.sql
```

However, the command `psql` isn´t recognised second host B. I mean I cannot run commands using `psql` B

what is then the difference between `psql`and `postgres-client`here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docker image postgresql-client has `psql` defined as an entrypoint. See https://github.com/jbergknoff/Dockerfile/blob/master/postgresql-client/Dockerfile#L3 .

So you basically ran `psql psql` and psql does not understand that. Just leave `psql` out and start straight with the args.

You can read up on CMD vs ENTRYPOINT here [What is the difference between CMD and ENTRYPOINT in a Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile) or here http://goinbigdata.com/docker-run-vs-cmd-vs-entrypoint/ .

Comment: Ah, ok. I understand.